How can I prevent qcow2 images used by KVM from growing indefinitely on the hypervisor's file system?
I have a number of KVM virtual machines that use qcow2 images to store their data on.
The size of the file system within the virtual machine is of course limited. Most of the time I use LVM with ext4 file systems.
The size of the qcow2 image on the hypervisor is limited as well, as can be seen by using qemu-img info:
image: my_vm.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 125 GiB (134217728000 bytes)
disk size: 173 GiB
cluster_size: 65536
Snapshot list:
ID        TAG               VM SIZE                DATE     VM CLOCK     ICOUNT
1         1714792201        19.7 GiB 2024-05-04 05:10:01 06:24:17.339           
2         1714878601        30.5 GiB 2024-05-05 05:10:01 30:22:58.504           
3         1714965001        30.6 GiB 2024-05-06 05:10:01 54:21:23.382           
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    compression type: zlib
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
    extended l2: false

Nevertheless, the qcow2 images on the hypervisor's file system keep growing so that I have to trim them every now and then which is annoying. I had cases where the virtual size was set to 150 GB and the qcow2 image had grown to more than 250 GB.
Is there any possibility to prevent the qcow2 image from growing beyond a predefined size?

I have to trim them every now and then can you expand on this. How do you trim them, and what is "every now and then"? What OS is running on the guest VMs?

@JaromandaX thanks for pointing this out. I usually use virt-sparsify to reduce the size of the image - sure there are may other ways, but this is what I mean when I talk about trimming, I simply mean the process of reducing the size of image on the hypervisor's file system. "Every now and then" is when there's not much space left on the file system and the reason is qcow2 images that have grown too large in size.

sure there are may other ways - are there?

What about just using raw images instead? Even if you start with a sparse image, it will never grow beyond the logical size of the file.

The cause of my problem is presumably my extensive use of snapshots.
Taken from here:
"A snapshot is a new sparse image, able to grow to the same size as the original. So if you take a 10Gb disk, fill it up to 10Gb, and then snapshot it, the snapshot will also be able to grow to 20Gb. In the long run, this is always a problem, which is one of the resons snapshots in production are never a good idea."
